# Converting for loop to do-while loop in C++

Tags: loops, do-while

Please help me convert this code to `do-while`  loop.

```
int i,j,k;

for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {

    for (j=1; j<i; j++)
        cout << " ";

    for (k=1; k<=6-i; k++)
            cout << "$";

    cout << endl;

}
```

this is what i got so far..

```
    do{

        j=5;
        do{
            do {
              cout <<"$";
              k--;
            } while(k>=1);

            j--;
        } while (j>=i);

        cout << endl;
        i++;

    } while(i<=5);
```

I can't seem to get the correct output...

expected output should be:

```
$$$$$
 $$$$
  $$$
   $$
    $
```

Comment: please help us by trying something.

Comment: sorry i forgot to post my code. just getting a hang of things here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i = 1;
do {

    int j = 1, k = 1;

    if (j < i) {
        do {
            cout << " ";
        } while (++j < i);
    }

    do {
        cout << "$";
    } while (k++ < 6 - i);

    cout << endl;

} while (i++ < 5);
```